# Login dialog appear in IE7 when browsing SQL Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server, iis, reporting-services, 64-bit

Setup is SQL2005 SP2 with Reporting Services installed local on Win2003 64bit.
When users browse report manager on http://server/reports they get login dialog for every request, but only if they use IE7. In FireFox all works.

The site is in "local intranet" zone on IE.

It seems like it is a NTLM, I've tested reinstall, change permission on service account, change permission on SRS directory, no works.

Comment: Any chance of getting a fiddler trace?  You can then determine if this is an NTLM vs Kerberos (negotiated) issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution!**

Change NTAuthenticationProviders on IIS with adsutil.vbs script to "NTLM,Negotiate" *(script found in \inetpub\adminscripts)*

run

```
cscript adsutil.vbs set w3svc/1/root/NTAuthenticationProviders "NTLM,Negotiate"
```

*(w3svc/1/ is the default website, change 1 to the right website nr)*

to verify settings run

```
cscript adsutil.vbs get w3svc/1/root/NTAuthenticationProviders
```

Answer (score 0):

Users can add the site http://server/reports to the trusted sites in Internet Explorer.

Menu: Tools->Internet Options
Tab: Security
Click on Trusted Sites icon
Click on Sites Button
Add your reports site

Answer (score 0):

Check the properties of your data source.  Many times the problem is an incorrect connection method:

Which are you using?

```
Connect using: 
 Credentials supplied by the user running the report 
  Display the following text to prompt user for a user name and password: 

 Use as Windows credentials when connecting to the data source 

 Credentials stored securely in the report server 
  User name:    
Password:    The password is not valid. Please retype the password. 


 Use as Windows credentials when connecting to the data source 
 Impersonate the authenticated user after a connection has been made to the data  source 

 Windows integrated security 
 Credentials are not required
```